# Speller CS50 - Valgrind gives error "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value"

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

Valgrind gives me an error and says it is in the line where I have `while (temp != NULL)`.

```c
bool check(const char* word)
{
    int hash_word_index = hash(word);

    if (table[hash_word_index] == NULL) {
        return false;
    } else if (table[hash_word_index] != NULL) {
        node* temp = table[hash_word_index];
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (strcasecmp(temp->word,word) == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: It could be on the line above. Is `table` guaranteed to exist? Incidentally, your `if (table[hash_word_index] != NULL)` check seems redundant - you can simplify by doing `node* temp = ...` right after the `hash` call and use `node` for checks.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind tend to also report usage of uninitialized value, if the value was acquired by copying an uninitialized value.

Thus in your case, the uninitialized value could from `table[hash_word_index]`, however, you're checking that value before, and it would have been detected too.

The uninitialized value can also come from `temp = temp->next;`, if on one occasion, `next` was left uninitialized, and I'm quite sure that your issue come from here.

Maybe using `--track-origins=yes` can give you more insight on were this uninitialized value come from.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Not really, but the phrasing is bad. I'll rephrase, thank for pointing it out.

Comment: yes, in the load function, i had to initialize next. thank you guys, it is fixed now